# Booking events with datetime

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a gym mini-game. But I got stuck.

I have sql table like this:

```
==============================================
id|date_start|date_end|active|gym_type|user_id
==============================================
```

The reason of making this table is to BOOK trainings, like this :

```
  ===================================================================
  id|   date_start        |     date_end     |active|gym_type|user_id
  ===================================================================
  1 | 2017-09-27 15:34:33 |2017-09-27 15:35:33| 1   |Running |   1
  ===================================================================
  2 | 2017-09-27 14:34:33 |2017-09-27 14:35:33| 0   |Fighting |  1
  ===================================================================
```

my PHP code:

```
    <?php

class GymLeveling
{

  private $db;
  private $user;
  private $leveling;
  private $inv;
  private $item;
  private $userattri;

  function __construct(Connection $db, User $user, LevelingSystem $leveling,Inventory $inv,Item $item,UserAttributes $userattri)
  {
    $this->db=$db;
    $this->_user=$user;
    $this->leveling=$leveling;
    $this->inv=$inv;
    $this->item=$item;
    $this->userattri=$userattri;

  }

  function returnTime($cate)
  { // Here I return the time to client
    $userid=$this->_user->getID();
    $query = $this->db->_getConnection()->prepare("SELECT date_end,date_start FROM gym_events where gym_type='$cate' AND user_id=".$userid);
    $query->execute();
    $exist = $query->fetchAll();
    if(!is_null($exist) && !empty($exist))
    {
      $value=strtotime($exist[0]["date_end"])-strtotime('now');

      return $value;
    }
  }

  function LevelStart($category,$type)
  { //My main booking function
    $item=$this->item->getGymItem($category,$type);
    $price=$itemXp=$item["Price"];
    $money=$this->userattri->getAttribute("money");
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Riga');
    $set_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+1 minutes'));
    $current=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $userid=$this->_user->getID();

    $query = $this->db->_getConnection()->prepare("SELECT * FROM gym_events where gym_type='$category' AND user_id=".$userid);
    $query->execute();
    $exist = $query->fetchAll();
    //var_dump($exist);
    //echo $exist[0]["gym_done"]."<br>";
    //var_dump($exist);
    //if($itemsrequire==TRUE){}

    if($money>$price) //if I have enough money
    {

    if(!is_null($exist) && !empty($exist)) // if training dosen't exist 
    {

      //echo $exist[0]["date_end"]."<br>";
      //echo $exist[0]["date_start"]."<br>";
      //echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

      while(date("Y-m-d H:i:s") <= $exist[0]["date_end"]) //While date time is greater than now()
      {
          echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        //if($exist[0]["active"]==1)
        //{
        $que=sprintf("UPDATE gym_events SET active=1  WHERE user_id=%d AND gym_type='%s'",$userid,$category);
        $query =  $this->db->_getConnection()->prepare($que);
        $result = $query->execute();

        if(!$result) {
           throw new Exception('DB error');
        }
        if(date("Y-m-d H:i:s") == $exist[0]["date_end"])
        {
          $que=sprintf("UPDATE gym_events SET active=0  WHERE user_id=%d AND gym_type='%s'",$userid,$category);
          $query =  $this->db->_getConnection()->prepare($que);
          $result2 = $query->execute();

          if(!$result2) {
             throw new Exception('DB error');
          }
        }
        //$this->Leveling($category,$type);

      //}

      }

      if(date("Y-m-d H:i:s") > $exist[0]["date_end"])
      {

        //if($exist[0]["active"]==0)
        //{
          $que=sprintf("UPDATE gym_events SET active=1, date_start='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."', date_end='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 minutes'))."' WHERE user_id=%d AND gym_type='%s'",$userid,$category);
          echo $que;
          $query =  $this->db->_getConnection()->prepare($que);
          $result = $query->execute();
          if(!$result) {
             throw new Exception('DB error');
        //  }

        //  echo "update start";

        }
      }
    }

    else
    {
      $query =  $this->db->_getConnection()->prepare("INSERT INTO gym_events (date_start,date_end,active,gym_type,gym_done,user_id) VALUES (:date_start,:date_end,1,:gym_type,0,:user_id)");
      $query->bindparam(":date_start",$current);
      $query->bindparam(":date_end",$set_time);
      $query->bindparam(":gym_type",$category);
      $query->bindparam(":user_id",$userid);
      $result = $query->execute();
      //$this->leveling->setxp(60,"str_xp");

    }
  }
    else
    {
      echo "No money";
    }

  }

}
```

I haven't commented all out and It could look like a messy code, sorry.

First function return time to client and creates a timer between date_start and end.

The variables in use like `$cate`, `$category` are sql `gym_types`

The second function firstly check's if any trainings,booking exist, if not it inserts.

Now comes the main function with while loop what should update `active=1` while not equal to the `date_end`. If later someone tries to book again, for that I made the if statement. `if(date("Y-m-d H:i:s") > $exist[0]["date_end"])`

**Now I have 2 problems with my project**

1. I dont want seprate gym_types to run, like I dont want 2 diffrent gym types to be `active=1` when function called, ONLY one can be active per user
2. I want to update column `active=0` when date_ends without calling the function again

The result I want is that, only one booking gymtype to be active per user when function called, and no other inserting updateing when it's still booked(active).

Comment: those aren't problems, those are requirements, or at least they're phrased like requirements. Which parts of the code attempt to implement those things, and what problems are you having with them? Unexpected behaviour? Error messages? Give specific examples using sample data if it's helpful.

Comment: Maybe I should ask for help in stack exchange. I have really difficult to explain how these "Mistakes" occur.

Comment: if you can't explain it, then it's quite hard for someone to help you, sorry